# How to prevent Poweshell not showing script processing data

Tags: powershell, out-of-the-box

I have created a powrshell script for updating SharePoint List. When i run it shows all the backend processing to the console for example all the list schema info. I want it only show script created Out put (The only output with Write-Host) and not out of the box backend processing. Is there any command available to prevent that?

it shows counting like below when I use .add method of ArrayList where ever in script

```
0
1
2
3
```

and it shows List XML Schema when i store List items in some variable in the script like below:

```
Sealed                      : False
Version                     : 28
DisplayFormTemplateName     : DocumentLibraryForm
EditFormTemplateName        : DocumentLibraryForm
NewFormTemplateName         : DocumentLibraryForm
NewFormUrl                  : 
MobileNewFormUrl            : 
EditFormUrl                 : 
MobileEditFormUrl           : 
DisplayFormUrl              : 
MobileDisplayFormUrl        : 
Id                          : 0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39009893A4DD0A05487AAE05EAE8D183333C003933922476541344B8A065CBACE8178D
ReadOnly                    : False
Name                        : NewsPage
NameResource                : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserResource
FeatureId                   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Description                 : Used to create news articles.
JSLink                      : 
DescriptionResource         : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserResource
Hidden                      : False
```

Comment: This script is regarding SharePoint Developlemt !!!

Comment: I have updated question.. please remove "On Hold"

Comment: I'm sorry, but you ask how to suppress output in powershell, that is not a SharePoint question since the answer is the same regardless of what cmdlets you use

Comment: find the line that's doing that (maybe SomeThing.Add()) and add " | Out-Null" in the end, and move on with your life :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `Out-Null option?` This suppresses output to the console.

Example: 
`Verb-Noun -param acb | Out-Null`

Comment: Where I put that in script, In the begining, right?

Comment: @SPBeginer, no, you add that at the end of all of the lines that are causing the output you don't want to see.  Just add `| Out-Null` at the end of each line.